# Is there a way to make sepcific custom fields show on a page's Wordpress admin interface only if they choose a specific template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to do something like this:

**Pseudo Code**

```
if ( thisAdminPage.template === Template_Id_1 )
{
    showCustomFieldOption( "SpecialField" );
}

else hideCustomFieldOption( "SpecialField" );
```

Then the admin user would see a text box (or whatever kind of field it is) on that admin page. But if they changed to a different template, the field would go away.

How do I do this?

Comment: Try to use use ACF plugin. It has more feature than you explained.

Comment: @ManeshTimilsina do you have a link to that plugin?

Comment: You can find it [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as seen in [this WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53557/12615), it's just a matter of adding some jQuery to the page edit screen and watch for changes in the template dropdown.

A meta box for test purposes:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box(
        'myplugin_sectionid',
        'Title', 
        function() {
            echo 'Test meta box';
        },
        'page'
    );
});
```

Then, print the script in `post.php` and `post-new.php` footer admin pages. You'll have to adjust `'onecolumn-page.php'` for your Page Template name and `#myplugin_sectionid` for your Meta Box:

```
foreach( array( 'post', 'post-new' ) as $hook )
    add_action( "admin_footer-$hook.php", 'enqueue_sopt_10564' );

function enqueue_sopt_10564()
{
    if( 'page' == get_current_screen()->id ) // Correct post type
    {
        echo <<<HTML
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

                /**
                 * Adjust visibility of the meta box at startup
                */
                if($('#page_template').val() == 'onecolumn-page.php') {
                    // show meta box
                    $('#myplugin_sectionid').show();
                    $("form#adv-settings label[for='myplugin_sectionid-hide']").show();
                } else {
                    // hide meta box
                    $('#myplugin_sectionid').hide();
                    $("form#adv-settings label[for='myplugin_sectionid-hide']").hide();
                }
                /**
                 * Live adjustment of the meta box visibility
                */
                $('#page_template').on('change', function(){
                    if($(this).val() == 'onecolumn-page.php') {
                        // show meta box
                        $('#myplugin_sectionid').show();
                        $("form#adv-settings label[for='myplugin_sectionid-hide']").show();
                    } else {
                        // hide meta box
                        $('#myplugin_sectionid').hide();
                        $("form#adv-settings label[for='myplugin_sectionid-hide']").hide();
                    }
                });                 
            });    
            </script>
HTML;
    } 

}
```

Comment: thank you. how would I use that to add a complex type as well? for example, `employeeInfo` that has a name, department and an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Advanced Custom Fields` plugin.

Download it from [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)